# How do I add the first and last name as a query result?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, inner-join

I am running a mySQL query to find an employee's manager by the manager's ID. I was able to get it work as follows:

```
SELECT e.first_name
     , m.first_name AS manager_name 
  FROM employee e 
  JOIN employee m 
    on e.manager_id = m.employee_id
```

However, I want to have the manager's first + last name in the result but I'm having trouble figuring out the right syntax to get it to concatenate.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only the e Data, and if your column is last_name

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(m.first_name,' ', m.last_name) AS manager_name 
FROM employee e 
JOIN employee m on e.manager_id = m.employee_id
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want string concatenation?

```
select e.first_name, 
    concat(m.first_name, ' ',  m.last_name) as manager_full_name
from employee e 
join employee m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id
```